# How to paste pictures into data frame?

Tags: qgis, polygon, photos

I have a polygon feature class and I want to trace (select with a polygon) a picture that is solely comprised of a couple of interlocking letters.

In ArcMap when I would do this I would simply drag the picture into the data frame and I could adjust the sized and position of it, trace, export, delete the picture and have a brand new layer in the shape that I wanted.

I don't see a way to do this in QGIS, when I drag a photo in I am then prompted to define the new layer's coordinate system. It doesn't seem to recognize that it is only a picture. Anyone know how I can simply drag in a picture to QGIS to trace it?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

If the picture has the size of the canvas, you could make a screen shot of the current canvas with `file -> Save as Picture...` . You get a world file (.jpgw or pngw) along with that picture.

If the size of the external picture does not match, use gimp to make it fit into it.

Just copy the world file and rename the first part to the name of the external picture you want to insert.

Insert that picture as raster layer, and choose the same CRS as the project has.

You get something like:

[image]

---

**Solution 2**

Georeferencing by selecting four points on the canvas should work as well:

Load the gif in the georeferencer, choose the same CRS as your current project (noted in the status bar), click near one corner of the picture, select to get coordinates from map and click there, and so on for all edges.

The points on the map should have nearly the same ratio (heigth/width) as the original picture.

Click on the yellow icon to set the new filename and again the CRS, then the green triangle icon to start the georeferencer.

Comment: How does that help?

Comment: @Nathan: You get the picture into the current canvas. Isn't that what Evan wants?

Comment: but yo would get the same result by just pressing OK on the projection selection dialog.

Comment: No, without a world file the picture will be inserted at (0,0). That might be totally wrong if you use a UTM projection with false Easting.

Comment: I appreciate the help Andre but to be honest that's all a bit above me. I have a .gif that is a pretty good size for my map. What is next? I add it in as a raster layer? How do I find out the coordinates/projection of my original map?

Comment: I expanded my answer for the georeferencer part. You find the current project CRS in the status bar once the map is loaded. You do not need to know the coordinates, just click on the map where the edges of the pictures shall be placed.